# html elements above three.js don't receive touches

Tags: mobile, three.js, touch

I've got some menu items above a Three.js scene that work well with a mouse, however, on mobile they don't receive any touches/clicks.

The html elements sit in the page, i.e. like this

```
    <div id='Three.js container' ></div>
    <div id='menu' ></div>
```

Here are the events

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
    document.addEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd, false );
```

Here is the touch handler in Three

```
function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {



    if (event.touches.length == 1) {

        event.preventDefault();

        onPointerDownPointerX = event.touches[0].pageX;
        onPointerDownPointerY = event.touches[0].pageY;

        onPointerDownLon = lon;
        onPointerDownLat = lat;

        mouse.x = ( event.touches[0].pageX/ window.innerWidth ) * 0.1;
        mouse.y = ( event.touches[0].pageY / window.innerHeight ) * 0.1;

        detectHotspotClick();

    }

    if (event.touches.length == 2) {

        _state = STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN;
        var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
        var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
        _touchZoomDistanceEnd = _touchZoomDistanceStart = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy ``);

    }

}
```

And the mouse click

```
    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    isUserInteracting = true;

    if(selectedHotspot && !viewingHotspot){
        TWEEN.removeAll(); 
        selectedHotspot = null;
    }

    onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
    onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

    onPointerDownLon = lon;
    onPointerDownLat = lat;

    // update the mouse variable
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    detectHotspotClick();

}
```

Anyone know how I can ensure the menu receives touch events?

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listener to the container div, rather than the document

```
 document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
```